# stuck in differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$(1+y^2)\frac{y}{x}+(1-y^2)\left(\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}\right)=0$$
$$(1-2y+y^2)dy=\frac{-2y^2}{x}$$

Try to separate $x$ and $y$

$$\int \left(1-2y+y^2\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=\int \frac{dx}{x}$$
$$ -\frac{1}{2y^2}+\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{2}dy=\ln x+c$$
$$\ln y + \frac{1-y^2}{2y}=\ln x+c$$

is my approach true?

but how can i continue from this? thanks!!

Comment: Your approach is a bit confusing, and gives a slightly wrong answer - the correct answer should look like $$\ln y+\frac{1}{2y^2}=2\ln x+c$$

Comment: thanks, it turned out that i miscalculated it.  should i  stop here or continue? $e^{2lnx+c}=e^{ln y +\frac{1}{2y^2}}$ ->$x^2.c=y.e^{\frac {1}{2y^2}}$ ->$y=\frac{x^2 c}{e^{\frac {1}{2y^2}}}$?

Comment: Yes, you have $$c x^2=y e^{\frac1{2y^2}}$$ which is correct. This is how I would leave the answer, since you have all the $x$'s on one side and the $y$'s on the other. It doesn't really matter though how you choose to write it. :)

Comment: ok thankyou so much!!! really appreciate for the help! :)

Comment: On the day you will learn about it, you will see that there is an explicit solution of $y$ in terms of Lambert function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to keep losing $dx$'s and such all over the place. Here's how to rearrange into separable form: $$(1+y^2)\frac yx=(y^2-1)\frac{dy}{dx}-(y^2-1)\frac yx\\\frac{y^3+y}x+\frac{y^3-y}x=(y^2-1)\frac{dy}{dx}\\\frac{2y^3}x=(y^2-1)\frac{dy}{dx}$$
From here, it should be clear how to separate $y$ and $x$, and integrate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you got to the second line. It's close, but the $dx$ is missing, and there's a $2y$ term that came out of nowhere.

Here's how I'd approach it. The first step is to try to separate out $dy/dx$

$$ (1+y^2)\frac{y}{x} + (1-y^2)\frac{dy}{dx} - (1-y^2)\frac{y}{x} = 0 $$
$$ (1+y^2)\frac{y}{x} - (1-y^2)\frac{y}{x} = (y^2-1)\frac{dy}{dx} $$

Factor out the LHS
$$ \big[(1+y^2) - (1-y^2) \big]\frac{y}{x} = (y^2-1)\frac{dy}{dx} $$
$$ 2y^2\frac{y}{x} = (y^2-1)\frac{dy}{dx} $$

Then divide out all the $y$'s from the LHS
$$ \frac{2}{x} = \frac{y^2-1}{y^3}\frac{dy}{dx} $$

You can take it from here.

Comment: thanks i got it and try to continue $e^{2lnx+c}=e^{ln y +\frac{1}{2y^2}}$ ->$x^2.c=y.e^{\frac {1}{2y^2}}$ ->$y=\frac{x^2 c}{e^{\frac {1}{2y^2}}}$